# Webkit transition difficulties in Safari

Tags: html, css, webkit, transition

My transition property is working in Chrome and FF but I can't seem to get it to work in Safari. I was hoping someone could please let me know if there were any errors in my code?  Thanks

```
transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
-webkit-transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
```

Comment: What version of Safari are you using? I've created a Codepen sketch and confirmed that it works in all browsers: http://cdpn.io/mpFCs. Your code could certainly be cleaned up, but its functional as is.

Comment: I'm testing this on Safari 5.  It's only underlining, but not showing the left-to-right transition like in other browsers.

Comment: In my example, or in your code? In the latter case, it would help to see what the associated HTML looks like to know what kind of element you are trying to affect.